# Sending serialized object from java program to servlet

Tags: java, serialization, servlets

I need to send a Java object from my Java program to Servlet. I thought of doing it by serialization. Is there any other thing I can use to send a Java object to Servlet. If it is by serialization can you give me the link for reference.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an HttpURLConnection, create a POST request, and before connecting to the server, get the outputStream from the HttpURLConnection, wrap it with an ObjectOutputStream, and write your object to it.

You will have to do the reverse on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got this working by the way you suggested

Answer (score 3):

The potential problem with sending serialized Java objects is that the client and webserver need to both have the right versions of all of the classes for all of the objects involved.

That's OK if you have control over the client and server sides and the ability to deploy new versions at will.  However, if you don't a better option might to be use JSON or XML instead of serialized Java objects.

Comment: Yeah!!! I would like to use this solution in future, if I find similar kind of situation. Actually, I used HttpURLConnection solution which is below. I found that even the package when the Serialized objects placed should be same in both the client and the server side. I placed the my serialized object in one package in client side and placed the same serialized obj in another package in server side. when reading the object, the server returned ClassNotFoundException. 

Probably, this solution is better

Answer (score 0):

Consider [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html). It sound like that to me.

Comment: Yes, but sticking to the Servlet for this might not be needed, if he/she has control over both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip103.html
http://www.cs.unc.edu/Courses/jbs/lessons/java/java_serialization/serverThreadedCO.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Hessian: http://hessian.caucho.com/

We use Hessian to send serialized Java objects from our Java rich client to our servlet.
Hessian can also be used in conjunction with the [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework).